# How to Send Custom Dimension using Link Click Event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like to set a user scope custom dimension when the user clicks a link.

I know this might be bad form, but with the CMS I am using I think my best bet is to embed the javascript directly in the link in an "onclick" attribute.

The only thing I have been able to find so far on this is the following, taken from [Exclude Yourself and Others from Google Analytics Data: 5 Ways to Do It](http://www.dirtyanalytics.com/exclude-people-from-google-analytics-data/):

```
<a onclick="ga('set', 'dimensionX', 'HideMe');" href="URL">Click to Set Cookie</a>
```

The thing is, I have always understood that you need to send custom dimensions and metrics along with a pageview or event hit... and I don't see an event here!

So I guess this is a bit of a two-parter (ish):

1. Will this work (admit I haven't tested it because it just looked bogus to me)?
2. How does it need to be altered to actually work? I think what I need to do is send an event and the custom dim at the same time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Sorry I didn't read your whole question, my mistake. So from [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) - with the configuration you have (after the user clicks that link), ga will send a custom dimension with all the hits on the current page (or for the lifetime of the tracker object). So any events that are fired afterwards will be sent like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
  'dimensionX': "HideMe"
});
```

---

Old answer:

Custom dimensions can only be set before the pageview is sent:

```
ga('set', 'dimensionX', 'foo');
ga('send', 'pageview', location.href);
```

You probably should use Custom Events for this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: Hi Rob! Yes that is what I am after; if you read my question you'll see that I am attempting to send the dimension along with an event type hit, not a pageview. Just don't know how to mash the whole thing together into a bit of javascript in the a tag! :)

Comment: @Drewdavid Doh! Sorry about that, I've updated with (hopefully) the answer to your *actual* question.

Comment: Thanks; I think I also may be having a "Doh!" moment. Didn't realize that I could put that code just as you have shown it right in the onclick... Seems to work a-ok! Thank you very much. :)